# How apply position/rotation change of one object to another in Three.js

Tags: three.js

In THREE.js, if I know objectA's position before and after a drag, how can I apply that position change to objectB using matrices? And what matrices do i need to represent position before/after?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show your code when you ask a question. In three.js, you generally do not need to mess with the matrix directly. Use `objectB.position.copy( objectA.position );` and `objectB.quaternion.copy( objectA.quaternion );`

Comment: So to apply a position change it would be objectB.position.copy(positionAfter - positionBefore)?

Comment: You need to show your code. It is not clear what you are trying to do.